# Topology of $\Bbb{Q}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, topological-groups, p-adic-number-theory

Let $a\in \Bbb{Q}_p$. Is $ a+p^x\Bbb{Z}_p$ an open set around $a$ in the topology of $\Bbb{Q}_p$. Here $x \in \Bbb{Z}$.  Also I have another question.
Is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ open in $\Bbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: They're both balls. The second is a specific case of the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is both open and closed because the valuation is discrete. The possible non-zero distances in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are $\{p^k:k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, so the next largest distance after 1 is $p$. That means $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is both the closed ball of radius $1$ around $0$ (by definition), and the open ball of radius $1+\epsilon$. In the same way, $p^k \mathbb{Z}_p$ is the open ball of radius $p^{-k}+\epsilon$ around 0, and $a+p^k \mathbb{Z}_p$ the same around $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try expressing those sets using the metric.

Comment: @Culter: Yes. I think $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is open because it is all elements of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with norm $1$. Hence $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is open. S0, $p^x\mathbb{Z}_p$ is open neighbourhood of zero. So $a+p^x\mathbb{Z}$ is open.

Comment: Almost! Where you write "with norm 1", I think you meant "with norm at most 1". Then you want to check that this closed ball is also an open ball, as Prometheus does.